# tar extension match using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a directory with some image files. I want to move all those files to a different place as long as they are not `tar` extensions. What is the regex in Java to filter `tar` files?

This is my code:

```
String regex = "^[[a-z]\\.[^tar]$]*";
```

Comment: Instead of regex, you can use `if(!filename.endsWith(".tar")) {//move}`

Comment: You could even use [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) to do it, but the above comment is probably a simpler method. FWIW, if you wanted to use a regex, you'd use `String regex = "\.tar$"` and use `! <matcher>.matches()` to get your result

Comment: In fact, you have to use the solutions from first 2 comments combined :)

Comment: `[^tar]` does not do what you think it does.  It matches **one character** that is not `t`, `a`, or `r`.  Actually, the outer square brackets probably change the meaning of everything.  I like the `endsWith` solution, but please find a tutorial on regexes--you need to learn the basics.

Comment: @Ryan J: The regex is defined in xml and loaded during initialization. So I can't change any exisitg Java code other than the regex itself. So doing an inverse match in java is not an option. I need the inverse operation inside Regex itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways.

**Use this regex**

```
^.*\.(?!tar).*$
```

**EndWith solution**

```
if(!filename.endsWith(".tar"))
```

**FileFilter** - [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html)

And probably a few more. I think the endsWith is the fastest way, not regex, because that's pretty heavy operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// implement the FileFilter interface and override the accept method
public class ImageFileFilter implements FileFilter
{
  private final String[] filterExtensions =
    new String[] {"tar"};

  public boolean accept(File file)
  {
    for (String extension : filterExtensions)
    {
      // if the file name does not end with the extension, you can accept it
      if (!file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you can get a list of files with this filter

```
File dir = new File("path\to\my\images");
String[] filesWithoutTars = dir.list(new ImageFileFilter());
// do stuff here
```

EDIT:
Since the OP says he can't modify the java code, the following regex should do what you want: `^.*(?!\.tar)$`

It will match anything from the beginning of the string, but asserts that the ".tar" portion at the end of the string will not match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.matches()` method to test a string for a match ignore case.

sample code:

```
String regex = "(?i).*\\.tar";
String fileName = "xyz.taR";
System.out.println(fileName.matches(regex)); // true
```